# Memory leak in background process on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, memory-leaks, delayed-job

I was wondering if anyone can advise me on how to track down a memory leak / issue on a background process on Heroku.

I have one dyno worker running with a delayed_job queue, processing all sorts of different processes. From time to time, I'm getting a sudden jump in the memory consumed. Subsequent jobs then exceed the memory limit and fail, and all Hell breaks loose.

The weird thing is I can't see that the jump in memory is connected to any particular job. Here's the sort of log I see:

```
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=load_avg_1m val=0.00 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=load_avg_5m val=0.01 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=load_avg_15m val=0.01 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_total val=133.12 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_rss val=132.23 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_cache val=0.88 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_swap val=0.01 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_pgpgin val=0 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_pgpgout val=45325 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:25 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=diskmbytes val=0 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=load_avg_1m val=0.15 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=load_avg_5m val=0.07 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=load_avg_15m val=0.17 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=memory_total val=110.88 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=memory_rss val=108.92 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=memory_cache val=1.94 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=memory_swap val=0.01 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=memory_pgpgin val=2908160 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=memory_pgpgout val=42227 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:31 vemmleads heroku/web.1:  source=heroku.10054113.web.1.bf5d3fae-2b1b-4e1d-a974-01d9fa4644db measure=diskmbytes val=0 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:35 vemmleads app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL measure.current_transaction=1008211 measure.db_size=482260088bytes measure.tables=39 measure.active-connections=6 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.99996 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=1 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=load_avg_1m val=0.00 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=load_avg_5m val=0.00 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=load_avg_15m val=0.14 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=memory_total val=108.00 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=memory_rss val=107.85 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=memory_cache val=0.15 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=memory_swap val=0.01 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=memory_pgpgin val=0 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=memory_pgpgout val=33609 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:45 vemmleads heroku/run.2472:  source=heroku.10054113.run.2472.e811164e-4413-4dcf-8560-1f998f2c2b4e measure=diskmbytes val=0 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=load_avg_1m val=0.30 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=load_avg_5m val=0.07 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=load_avg_15m val=0.04 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_total val=511.80 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_rss val=511.78 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_cache val=0.00 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_swap val=0.02 units=MB 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_pgpgin val=27303936 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=memory_pgpgout val=154826 units=pages 
Aug 15 07:13:46 vemmleads heroku/worker.1:  source=heroku.10054113.worker.1.4589e3f4-8208-483a-a927-67c4c1cbee46 measure=diskmbytes val=0 units=MB
```

The memory usage of worker.1 jumps from 108.00 to 551.80 for no apparent reason. It doesn't look like any jobs were processed during that time, so it's hard to understand where that giant chomp of memory comes from. Some way later in the log, worker1 hits the memory limit and fails.

I have NewRelic Pro running. It doesn't help at all - in fact it doesn't even create alerts for the repeated memory errors. The above Heroku logs give me no more information.

Any ideas or pointers about what to investigate next would be appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information here to pinpoint what's going on.

The most common cause of memory leaks in Rails applications (especially in asynchronous background jobs) is a failure to iterate through large database collections incrementally.  For example, loading all User records with a statement like `User.all`

For example, if you have a background job that is going through every `User` record in the database, You should use `User.find_each()` or `User.find_in_batches()` to process these records in chunks (default is 1000 for ActiveRecord).

This limits the working set of objects loaded into memory while still processing all of the records.

You should look for un-bounded database lookups that could be loading huge numbers of objects.

Comment: I am having memory leak even after using find_each and batching in my sidekiq background jobs. The problem is that ActiveRecord QueryCache is enabled in background jobs by default, making batching useless.  https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting